# How to execute a task when a new element is INSERTED into a table in Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to execute a task when a new element is `INSERTED` into a table in `Microsoft SQL Management Studio`.

I Have a `dbo.EmergencyAlarm` tables in `SSMS`. In this table I have a column `DeviceId`. I'm looking for a solution that automaticaly put this device ID in a txt file or in the clipboard when a new alarm is coming.

One solution will be to query the database every 2 seconds and test if a new element is created.

Is there a **Easiest** solution (like an `Event trigger`) incorporated in `SSMS` ?

Comment: SSMS is merely a GUI for sql server, it has no database functionality of its own.

Comment: Actually just check how database triggers work and how to write on a file using SQL

Comment: Would you be better firing an email?

Comment: Not really ! The idea at end is to send an HTTP POST request with the ID as parameter !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [After Insert trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) then populate data from your trigger into a specific queue.
You can even create a queue table, and using a periodic job process the data in your queue table. Your job can simple create text files with [SQL BCP command](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-output-to-file-using-sql-server-bcp-command.aspx)

```
declare @id int = 456
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)
SET @cmd = 'bcp "select ''' + convert(varchar(10), @id) + '''" queryout "c:\textfile.txt" -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost"'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```